# SSRS - Converting a value into a number causing issues when working with a NULL value

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have an expression in SSRS that is designed to change the format of a field depending on the value of another field:

```
=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!RD.Value), "", IIF(InStr(Fields!ReportHeader_f2.Value,"Average") > 0,Format(Fields!RD.Value,"N") * 1.000,Format(Fields!RD.Value,"#,##;(#,##)") * 1.000))
```

I need the values to turn up as numbers in the excel spread sheet so I multiply them by 1.000 (I have also tried Cdbl).

When the expression encounters a `NULL` value for `RD`, the `#Error` cell pops up. I've tried using the `ISNOTHING()` tag to account for it and I've tried turning the `NULL` values into zeroes and then accounting for that.

What could be wrong with my expression?

Comment: Have you tried in the first condition to look for blank as well? `ISNOTHING(Fields!RD.Value) OR Fields!RD.Value = ""`

Comment: Thanks for reaching back, Wei. I just tried this - this didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me it looks like your `IsNothing` isn't catching `NULL` values and the error arises when SSRS tries to format the `NULL` value but doesn't have a way to handle that.  Personally, my preferred solution to this would be to make sure any `NULL` values are converted to zeroes in the query/proc prior to coming into the report.  Just slap an `ISNULL(RD, 0)` and try to handle the zero in the report. I'd also try to `CDbl` basically everything coming into this expression just to be sure nothing is coming in with a wrong datatype. Probably a better option than trying to multiply each by 1.000.  Additionally, the error could come from trying to multiply the formatted field by 1.000. 
 SSRS works in mysterious ways.  I would think this should work.

```
=IIF(CDbl(Fields!RD.Value) = 0.0, 
     "", 
     IIF(InStr(Fields!ReportHeader_f2.Value, "Average") > 0, 
         Format(CDbl(Fields!RD.Value), "N"),
         Format(CDbl(Fields!RD.Value), "#,##;(#,##)")))
```

You might also be able to replace the `CDbl` conversions with `Format(Fields!RD.Value * 1.000, "N")`, etc...  There's a few places things could've gone wrong, but this approach seems the most likely to work, IMO.

Another potential solution I explored with my testing was to create a calculated field based on the original field. For example, call it `RD2` and set the value equal to `=IIF(Fields!RD.Value Is Nothing OR Fields!RD.Value = 0, 0, Fields!RD.Value)`.  Then you can use the expression above with the `RD2` calculated field.  Seemed to catch the zero values in my testing.

Comment: That did it! I had the column return zero on IsNull in the SQL and used your SSRS snippet. I did have to add another parenthesis to the end. If you edit your solution to include the extra parenthesis, I'll mark it as the solution. Thank you for your time, Steve-o!! EDIT: Spoke too soon -- the values don't seem to be returning as numbers in the excel sheet. I'll need to investigate on this...

Comment: Done.  Happy to assist.

Comment: @ScottS. Was too late to edit my comment but I'm wondering if the `Format` in some cases changes the value to a string...  Not really sure, but you may be better off just bringing the value over and using Excel to format the value accordingly.

Comment: I figured out what it was. It was the Format line with the "#,##;...etc" piece. SSRS doesn't appear to like when you multiply a string with a double. Client might not like the omission of the comma but I think they would prefer the number format. I'm still going to mark your answer, Steve-o...it led me to what eventually worked: =IIF(CDbl(Fields!RD.Value) = 0.0, 
     "", 
     IIF(InStr(Fields!ReportHeader_f2.Value, "Average") > 0, 
         Format(CDbl(Fields!RD.Value), "N") * 1.000,
         Format(CDbl(Round(Fields!RD.Value)), "N") * 1.000))

Comment: @ScottS. Can you just do the multiplication before you format?  Like `Format(CDbl(Round(Fields!RD.Value *1.000)), "#,##;(#,##)")`?

Comment: Last comment for this thread: I just tried your suggestion - it still returned as a text field in Excel. Thanks again for your time and help.

Comment: @ScottS. It is the `Format` function that is converting the cell to text rather than numeric. Check my answer on how to get numeric values exported to Excel.

Answer (score 0):

1- You can use ISNOTHING function:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!RD.Value),0,Fields!RD.Value)
```

2- Develop a custom query. Open Report menu->Report Properties->Code, and use:

```
Function IfNullUseZero(myvalue as object)
     IF IsNull(myvalue) then
            Return 0
     Elseif myvalue =" " then
            Return 0
End If
```

then, on the report, do `=Code.IfNullUseZero(Fields!RD.Value)`.

Ref: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bd6dfd75-feb6-4093-8909-6c4054b64c96/convert-null-to-0-in-ssrs?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: Thanks for reaching back, Eray. When I try the code you pasted, I'm getting an error in the preview screen: 'IsNull' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. Any idea what that might be about?

Comment: Tried that. No error message but it didn't resolve the initial problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things happening here causing problems:

Firstly, `IIF` is a **function** not a language construct. This means there is no logic short-circuit depending on the value of the first parameter comparison, it *evaluates all parameters* before calling the function. So if either the True or False parameter would have an error, the whole thing will blow up regardless of the value of the conditional.

To prevent this you generally need to arrange two `IIF` function calls in a way that no error will be encountered. Now to the source of your problem: `CDbl` will throw an error if it encounters non-numeric input. The answer by @Steve-o169 prevents this by using two `IIF` functions in a way so that no invalid conversion is done, preventing the error. Another way would be to use the `Val` function rather than `CDbl` because the `Val` function does numeric evaluations without throwing an error - it just grabs what it can and calls that a number.

However, you don't actually need to worry about this because presentation should be separate from data: you want the `Value` to be numeric, otherwise if you use the `Format` function then exporting to Excel will have text values rather than numeric. Rather than put the formating in the `Value` expression you should put it in the `Format` property where it belongs, so the values will export as numbers and the format will also be correct in Excel.

So we don't even have to worry about the value of the field, just set the expression of the `Value` property to the field value so it will export as a number.

Now to set the `Format` correctly, in the `Format` property of your cell use the following expression:

```
=IIF(InStr(Fields!ReportHeader_f2.Value, "Average") > 0, "N", "#,##;(#,##)")
```